How to get user information like email, firstname and lastname using Windows AD and without LDAP server?
Using Windows AD in identity server to authenticate user and in that response we are not getting user information like e-mail, first name, last name.
To get the user information, we are using this code:
Thread.GetDomain().SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsPrincipal principal = (WindowsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

UserPrincipal up;

using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
     up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, principal.Identity.Name);

     // or return up.GivenName + " " + up.Surname;
}

But it throws an exception "LDAP Server unavailable" and this server can't be contacted.
How to get the user information without using that unavailable LDAP server?

Windows AD IS LDAP - so this doesn't really make a lot of sense .... not sure if you can configure Duende IdentityServer to return that information in the auth response (JWT) somehow, so you don't have to go grab it separately ... check the Duende documentation!
